# How to do Slick configuration via application.conf from within custom sbt task?

Tags: scala, sbt, slick

I want to create an set task which creates a database schema with slick. For that, I have a task object like the following in my project:

```
object CreateSchema {

    val instance = Database.forConfig("localDb")

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val createFuture = instance.run(createActions)
        ...
        Await.ready(createFuture, Duration.Inf)
    }

}
```

and in my `build.sbt` I define a task:

```
lazy val createSchema = taskKey[Unit]("CREATE database schema")

fullRunTask(createSchema, Runtime, "sbt.CreateSchema")
```

which gets executed as expected when I run `sbt createSchema` from the command line.

However, the problem is that `application.conf` doesn't seem to get taken into account (I've also tried different scopes like `Compile` or `Test`). As a result, the task fails due to `com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'localDb'`.

**How can I fix this so the configuration is available?**

*I found a lot of questions here that deal with using the `application.conf` inside the `build.sbt` itself, but that is not what I need.*

Comment: I assume `CreateSchema` and `application.conf` in sources/resources of your SBT project, right?

Comment: @ghik no, both are part of the main project (the one which is built by sbt). I want to avoid having duplicate configurations, so this task (which executes fine with the project code) should really use the same configuration the main project uses. So, application.con is in src/main/resources

Comment: that's exactly what I meant

Comment: @ag5: From where do you want to access application.conf, from within SBT code or from within some code you have written, but called by some custom SBT "run" command. I ask, as your statement " ..using the application.conf inside the build.sbt itself, but that is not what I need." is irritating.

Comment: @MartinSenne the code that accesses the application.con resides in the project which is built; if I call it e.g. on application start, it works fine. However, this code is called from a custom run command, and then it doesn't find the application.con

Comment: @ag5: See my new posted answer.

Comment: @ag5: Could you try my minimal example project?

Answer (score 3):

I have setup a little demo using SBT 0.13.8 and Slick 3.0.0, which is working as expected. (And even without modifying "-Dconfig.resource".)

## Files

#### ./build.sbt

```
name := "SO_20150915"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe"                 % "config"                 % "1.3.0"                            withSources() withJavadoc(),
  "com.typesafe.slick"          %% "slick"                  % "3.0.0",
  "org.slf4j"                    % "slf4j-nop"              % "1.6.4",
  "com.h2database"               % "h2"                     % "1.3.175"
)

lazy val createSchema = taskKey[Unit]("CREATE database schema")

fullRunTask(createSchema, Runtime, "somefun.CallMe")
```

#### ./project/build.properties

```
sbt.version = 0.13.8
```

#### ./src/main/resources/reference.conf

```
hello {
  world = "buuh."
}

h2mem1 = {
  url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test1"
  driver = org.h2.Driver
  connectionPool = disabled
  keepAliveConnection = true
}
```

#### ./src/main/scala/somefun/CallMe.scala

```
package somefun

import com.typesafe.config.Config
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._

/**
 * SO_20150915
 * Created by martin on 15.09.15.
 */
object CallMe {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    println("Hello")
    val settings = new Settings()

    println(s"Settings read from hello.world: ${settings.hw}" )

    val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")
    try {
      // ...
      println("Do something with your database.")
    } finally db.close
  }

}

class Settings(val config: Config) {

  // This verifies that the Config is sane and has our
  // reference config. Importantly, we specify the "di3"
  // path so we only validate settings that belong to this
  // library. Otherwise, we might throw mistaken errors about
  // settings we know nothing about.
  config.checkValid(ConfigFactory.defaultReference(), "hello")

  // This uses the standard default Config, if none is provided,
  // which simplifies apps willing to use the defaults
  def this() {
    this(ConfigFactory.load())
  }

  val hw = config.getString("hello.world")
}
```

## Result

If running `sbt createSchema` from Console I obtain the output

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/.../SO_20150915/project
[info] Set current project to SO_20150915 (in build file:/home/.../SO_20150915/)
[info] Running somefun.CallMe 
Hello
Settings read from hello.world: buuh.
Do something with your database.
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed 15.09.2015 10:42:20
```

### Ideas

- Please verify that this unmodified demo project also works for you.
- Then try changing SBT version in the demo project and see if that changes something.
- Alternatively, recheck your project setup and try to use a higher version of SBT.

Comment: Yes it works and after hours and hours of trial and error I finally found the actual problem: it was the `$` at the end of `DropSchema$` in my task definition. Which is really wird because at one point I had to add it in the first place, because otherwise the `DropSchema` class would not be found. What. the f.... Anyway thanks for your detailed answers.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

So, even if your code resides in your `src`-folder, it is called from within SBT. That means, you are trying to load your `application.conf` from **within the classpath context** of SBT.

**Slick** uses Typesafe `Config` internally. (So the approach below (described in background) is not applicable, as you can not modify the Config loading mechanism itself).

Instead try the set the path to your `application.conf` explicitly via `config.resource`, [see typesafe config docu (search for config.resource)](https://github.com/typesafehub/config)

#### Option 1

Either set `config.resource` (via -Dconfig.resource=...) before starting `sbt`

#### Option 2

Or from within build.sbt as Scala code

`sys.props("config.resource") = "./src/main/resources/application.conf"`

#### Option 3

Or create a `Task` in SBT via

```
lazy val configPath = TaskKey[Unit]("configPath", "Set path for application.conf")
```

and add

```
configPath := Def.task {
  sys.props("config.resource") = "./src/main/resources/application.conf"
}
```

to your sequence of settings.

Please let me know, if that worked.

### Background information

Recently, I was writing a custom plugin for SBT, where I also tried to access a `reference.conf` as well. Unfortunately, I was not able to access any of `.conf` placed within `project`-subfolder using the default `ClassLoader`.

In the end I created a `testenvironment.conf` in `project` folder and used the following code to load the (typesafe) config:

```
def getConfig: Config = {
  val classLoader = new java.net.URLClassLoader( Array( new File("./project/").toURI.toURL ) )
  ConfigFactory.load(classLoader, "testenvironment")
}
```

or for loading a genereal `application.conf` from `./src/main/resources`:

```
def getConfig: Config = {
  val classLoader = new java.net.URLClassLoader( Array( new File("./src/main/resources/").toURI.toURL ) )
  // no .conf basename given, so look for reference.conf and application.conf
  // use specific classLoader
  ConfigFactory.load(classLoader)
}
```

Comment: Option 2 doesn't work, because that doesn't even compile inside a build.sbt; I've tried Option 3, but that doesn't work either - it seems to override what the actual task definition should execute. How am I supposed to combine the `fullRunTask` stuff with the task-specific `sys.properties` configuration?

Comment: The line of code in Option 2 is Scala code and can of course not directly be inserted into .sbt or build.scala. It is meant to be placed in `CreateSchema` to set the system property **before** you initialize Slick via `Database.forConfig( ... )`.